# Parsing textual format into models

Tags: java, scala, parsing, nlp

Simplifying my problem, I have the following text that looks like this, it can come in a few formats, but you get the jist I hope:

`My name is Sam and my age is 15 & Name: Tony, Age: 6`

I am looking to parse it into a model like this:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
case class ParsedPeople(people: List[Person])
```

I could manually write a parser but given the text formats I have are considerably more complex I feel this would grow and become very cumbersome to maintain.

I expect this is a solved problem and there are many libraries out there that will a take some text, give it a "definition" (probably textual format) and it will parse into some POJOs (preferably Scala in my case, but I could deal with Java)?

How can this be achieved without writing and maintaining my own parser?

Comment: Can you split tokens on `&` ?

Comment: Yes, and there is an implicit `&` at the beginning. There will be synonyms for `&` aswell like `+`, `and`, ... However, I'm not sure how this changes the answer? I know there is Scala pattern matching, but i'd still have to write a fair chunk of code for that I expect.